# What's the easiest way to run Drupal site with PostgreSQL on Windows 10?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I tried a lot of different tools like Acquia, but most of them support only MysQL/Mariadb. What's the easiest way to run Drupal with postgres? Do I have to create Virtualbox VM from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create VM box from scratch - just find one that fulfill drupal requirements. Even more you have some suggested by Drupal community:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/local-server-setup/virtual-machine-development-environments

I'm personally using box "`geerlingguy/ubuntu1804`" with vagrant, additionally configured with ansible (by somebody else).

And IMHO it's better to us VM for at least 2 strong reasons:

- If someone else is working on project with you with VM he will also have identical working environment.
- When you decide to launch your site it will most likely run on linux box.

And it's better to avoid "unpredictable" problems when you decide to move project to other server.